# Eloquent eating up memory - Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, apache, laravel, eloquent

I tried working today however I got interrupted by this error:

```
[Tue Aug 05 09:08:48 2014] [error] [client 93.103.209.208] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /var/www/dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquuent/Model.php on line 643
```

The controller/method that results in the error:

```
public function show($id)
{
 return $this->layout->content = View::make('users.show', array(
  'user' => User::find($id)
 ));
}
```

However if I replace `User::find($id)` with `DB::table('users')->where('id', '=', $id)->first();` it works like a charm. What is going on here with Eloquent ?

I tried increasing my `memory_limit` in php.ini for apache & cli to 200-230M but it did not help. I also tried setting it to -1 to be unlimited just to see if it would work but no then i simply get no response from the server. And yes I did restart apache after every change.

**CAUSE**

The problem was a result of having a relation method in my User model to it self. Basically in my User class I had `User { public function user() { return $this->hasOne('User'); } }` which created a loop.

Comment: How apropos I just saw this: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/496469732392857601

Comment: @deceze I will agree on that.

Comment: Do you happen to have `with = ['user'];` set on that model?

Comment: @deczoI had a relation defined to the model it self.

Answer (score 2):

Just dissecting the error message - you have a memory limit of 128MB setup for PHP, the line in question is trying to allocate an additional ~131KB

The variables using the rest of the memory might not be related to this function, it could well just be the case that this part of the code looking for its 131KB is just consistently pushing you over the 128MB limit.

I'd use some logging mechanism to record the return value of [memory_get_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) at various points in your code. This should hopefully give you some indication of when the memory's being allocated and allow you to figure out how to optimise the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following:

```
...
return $this->layout->content = View::make('users.show')->with(array('user' => User::find($id)));
...
// or WITHOUT return
$this->layout->content = View::make('users.show')->with(array('user' => User::find($id)));
```

Comment: No it won't works just as well with or without return statement. Also not the issue;

Comment: Alright, do you have a screenshot of the Laravel debugger?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs that Laravel generates the script it stopped from executing by PHP/Apache for using to much memory and it occurs when Eloquent class is involved.

Comment: @kellax I have changed the code above, maybe that works? Let me know ;)

Comment: Nope. Also it's the same thing. With or without return it will not go into an infinite loop. I found the problem.